# What is the relation between spot price and future price if the goods are not produced yet?

Tags: futures

I read on the Internet that future price = spot price + carrying cost.

What if I buy a future before the goods/assets are even being manufactured.

Will I get a discount on the spot price since I commit in advance? Or it still depends on the expectation of price in the future?

Answer (score 1):

In these cases, for example an agricultural crop which is not produced yet, expectations enter into the pricing and it is no longer just spot_price+carrying cost like it is for a *storable commodity*. Textbooks love (and perhaps overemphasize) the 'store and deliver case' because it is so simple, but it is not the only consideration in general.

The existence and sign of a Risk Premium that would cause the futures price to be slightly below or slightly above the expected spot price, is an unsolved research issue on which there is no agreement. The (controversial) theory of [Normal Backwardation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_backwardation) claims the futures price is normally slightly below the expectation. (Because the Producers (short sellers of futures) are more active in hedging than the Buyers of the commodity).

Answer (score 0):

Well, how do you know if the good were already produced? In fact, probably most of soft commodities for long dated contracts weren't produced yet.

This "extra risk" is a type of credit risk, the risk of not receiving the payment or good. If it will affect the price or not is a matter of contract specificities.

If the contract is traded in a exchange, the credit risk is small, as the exchange will bear this risk and will demand collateral or insurance from buyers and sellers. In this scenario, the future price should be close to spot + carry.

If the contract is an over-the-counter between trader and producer, this relation might deviate to include the credit risk.